# Signed int range confusion

Tags: c, int, signed

This question might be very basic but i post here only after days of googling and for my proper basic understanding of signed integers in C.

Actually some say signed int has range

1. -32767 to 32767 and others say it has range
2. -32768 to 32767

Let us have int a=5 (signed / let us consider just 1 byte)

*the 1st representation of a=5 is represented as 00000101 as a positive number and a=-5 is represented as 10000101 (so range -32767 to 32767 justified)
(here the msb/sign bit is 1/0 the number will be positive/negative and rest(magnitude bits) are unchanged )

*the 2nd representation of a=5 is represented as 00000101 as a positive number and a=-5 is represented as 11111011
(the msb is considered as -128 and the rest of bits are manipulated to obtain -5) (so range -32768 to 32767 justified)

So I confuse between these two things. My doubt is what is the actual range of signed int in c ,1) or 2)

Comment: You already answered your question. What are you asking for? Maybe you want to search for "representation of signed integers". Also note both assumptions are actually not the full truth.

Comment: int in C has no fixed specified size. Only the minimum is defined. In 2's complement an n-bit type has range from `-2^(n-1)` to `2^(n-1)-1`

Comment: It depends in the underlying platform, if it's using [one's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones'_complement) or [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) (two's complement being the common one). As for the bit-size, it also depends, and these days `int` is usually 32 bits.

Comment: Read up here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Comment: The actual range of `signed int` is `[INT_MIN ...INT_MAX]`.  The range is _at least_ `[-32767 ... 32767]`.  That's it.  If you are concern about bit representation, use `unsigned`

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your environment and typically `int` can store -2147483648 to 2147483647 if it is 32-bit long and two's complement is used, but C specification says that `int` can store **at least** -32767 to 32767.

Quote from [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types <limits.h>

> Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
>
> — minimum value for an object of type int
>   INT_MIN  -32767 // −(2 <sup>15</sup> − 1)
>   — maximum value for an object of type int
>   INT_MAX  +32767 // 2 <sup>15</sup> − 1`

Answer (score 3):

Today, signed ints are usually done in [two's complement notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

The highest bit is the "sign bit", it is set for all negative numbers.

This means you have seven bits to represent different values.

With the highest bit unset, you can (with 16 bits total) represent the values 0..32767.

With the highest bit **set**, and **because you already have a representation for zero**, you can represent the values -1..-32768.

This is, however, **implementation-defined**, other representations do exist as well. The **actual** range limits for signed integers on your platform / for your compiler are the ones found in your environment's [`<limits.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits). That is the **only** definite authority.

On today's desktop systems, an `int` is usually 32 or 64 bits wide, for a correspondingly much larger range than the 16-bit 32767 / 32768 you are talking of. So either those people are talking about *really old* platforms, *really old* knowledge, embedded systems, or the *minimum **guaranteed** range* -- the standard states that `INT_MIN` must be *at least* -32767, and `INT_MAX` be *at least* +32767, the lowest common denominator.

Comment: if signed bits are usually done in 2's complement form,then obviously -32768 to 32767 must be the range right?then what do they mean by atleast -32767 to atleast 32767

Comment: 100s of millions of processors in 2015 are made with 8 and 16-bit registers and compilers used to program these embedded processors use 16-bit `int`.  C is very popular there.  Hardly _really old platforms_.

Comment: @adi: The standard does not guarantee two's complement notation (as I wrote, other notations exist). The standard also does not specify 16-bit width of type `int` (obviously). So all the standard *guarantees* is exactly what I wrote: `INT_MIN` must be *at least* -32767, and `INT_MAX` be *at least* +32767. I don't know a single system that defines these two constants to *exactly* those values, they are just the *guaranteed minimum* for either.

Comment: @chux: I keep forgetting *either* "old" *or* "small" in enumerations like that. Amended the answer, since you are, of course, correct. I remember a piece titled "All the life on earth are insects" that points out that, in numbers of units, 8 and 16 bit processors outnumber the "real" desktop CPUs by several orders of magnitude. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> My doubt is what is the actual range of signed int in c ,1) `[-32767 to 32767]` or 2) `[-32768 to 32767]`?

The whole point of C and its advantage of high portability to old and new platforms is that code **should not care**.

C defines the range of `int` with 2 macros:  `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`.  The C spec specifies:
`INT_MIN` is -32,767 *or less*.
`INT_MAX` is +32,767 *or more*.

If code needs a 16-bit 2's complement type, use `int16_t`.  If code needs a 32-bit or wider type, use `long` or `int32least_t`, etc.  Do not code assuming `int` is something that it is not defined to be.

Comment: thank u for the response.so when a code is in need of 2's complement and sign/magnitude representation?

Comment: @adi  1) When code need 2's complement, use exact width types like `uint8_t`, `int64_t`, etc.  2) If code needs _sign/magnitude representation_, - cannot help you there.  3) But most of all, avoid coding where a particular underlying representation is needed.  4)  When working with individual bits, etc., use unsigned types.

Comment: is the datatype range compiler dependent or computer architecture dependent?

Comment: @adi  The compiler has ultimate control as it can create code, likely inefficient, that causes the underlying hardware to be irrelevant.  But that is theoretical.  Real compliers attempt to work in harmony with the underlying hardware, therefore the the hardware drives the architecture.  Further the C spec drives things too.

Comment: @adi  An 8-bit processor will still have a 16-bit (or wider) `int`. So "datatype range" is 1) driven by C specification 2) compiler/hardware working in tandem to meet #1.

Comment: I would like to point out that the exact-width type are not necessarily supported on all platforms. ;-) HAH! Got 'cha! :-D

Comment: @DevSolar C11dr §7.20.1.1 3 details the degree of option concerning exact-width integer types.  On platforms that do not support an exact width type that OP code needs, the issue is moot.  To avoid that limitation, my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725455/signed-int-range-confusion/35726771?noredirect=1#comment59129551_35726771) encouraged: "avoid coding where a particular underlying representation is needed".

Answer (score 0):

The value `32767` is the maximum positive value you can represent on a signed 16-bit integer. The `C` corresponding type is `short`.

The `int` type is represented on at least the same number of bytes as `short` and at most the same number of bytes as `long`. The size of `int` on 16-bit processors is 2 bytes (the same as `short`). On 32-bit and higher architecture, the size of `int` is 4 bytes (the same as `long`).

No matter the architecture, the minumum value of `int` is [`INT_MIN`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) and the maximum value of `int` is [`INT_MAX`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits).

Similar, there are constants to get the minimum and maximum values for `short` (`SHRT_MIN` and `SHRT_MAX`), `long`, `char` etc. You don't need to use hardcoded constants or to guess what is the minimum value for `int` on your system.

---

The representation #1 is named ["sign and magnitude representation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Sign-and-magnitude_method). It is a theoretical model that uses the most significant byte to store the sign and the rest of the bytes to store the absolute value of the number. It was used by some early computers, probably because it seemed a natural map of the numbers representation in mathematics. However, it is not natural for binary computers.

The representation #2 is named [`two's complement`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement). The two's-complement system has the advantage that the fundamental arithmetic operations of addition, subtraction, and multiplication are identical to those for unsigned binary numbers (as long as the inputs are represented in the same number of bits and any overflow beyond those bits is discarded from the result). This is why it is the preferred encoding nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard specifies the lowest limits for integer values. As it is written in the Standard (5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types )

> 1. ...Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or **greater in
>      magnitude** (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.

For objects of type `int` these lowest limits are

— minimum value for an object of type int

```
INT_MIN -32767 // −(215 − 1)
```

— maximum value for an object of type int

```
INT_MAX +32767 // 215 − 1
```

For the two's complement representation of integers the number of positive values is one less than the number of negative values. So if only tow bytes are used for representations of objects of type int then `INT_MIN` will be equal to `-32768`.

Take into account that 32768 in magnitude is greater than the value used in the Standard. So it satisfies the Standard requirement.

On the other habd for the representation "sign and magnitude" the limits (when 2 bytes are used) will be the same as shown in the Standard that is `-32767:32767`

So the actual limits used in the implementation depend on the width of integers and their representation.